# extracting html table with filled in radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have table which contains several radio buttons. After selecting a radio button and clicking a button, the html of the table (including the filled in radio button) should be stored in a variable. However, only the html table is stored in a variable (i.e. there is no checked property in the stored html code).

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <form>
     <table id="satisfaction_table">
            <tr>
             <th>Nr</th>
             <th>Question</th>
             <th>1 (Unacceptable)</th>
             <th>2 (Poor)</th>
             <th>3 (Average)</th>
             <th>4 (Good)</th>
             <th>5 (Excellent)</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
             <td>1</td>
             <td>Did you call more than once before your call was answered?</td>
             <td><input type="radio"></td>
             <td><input type="radio"></td>
             <td><input type="radio"></td>
             <td><input type="radio"></td>
             <td><input type="radio"></td>
            </tr>
      </table>
    </form>


    <button type="button" onClick="extract_table()">Extract</button>

      <script>
      function extract_table()
      {

       // store html table
       var table = $('form').html();
       alert(table);

      }

     </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What are you planning to do with the content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reflect the checked or other applied `properties`, if you loop the items and set as `attributes` before getting `html()`.

```js
function extract_table() {
  var table = $('form');
  $('form :radio').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('checked', this.checked);
  })
  alert(table.html());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <table id="satisfaction_table">
    <tr>
      <th>Nr</th>
      <th>Question</th>
      <th>1 (Unacceptable)</th>
      <th>2 (Poor)</th>
      <th>3 (Average)</th>
      <th>4 (Good)</th>
      <th>5 (Excellent)</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Did you call more than once before your call was answered?</td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>

<button type="button" onClick="extract_table()">Extract</button>
```